# QGIS loads NetCDF data offset from map

Tags: qgis, python, netcdf

I have a standard NetCDF file with sea surface temperatures, with longitude values ranging from 0 to 360°. When I load it in QGIS, the right half of the data is plotted off the map of the projection of the Earth, like this:

[image: Image showing sea surface temperature being plotted to the right of the Earth map in QGIS]

I have tried many solutions to resolving this without success. I tried a number of reprojections using different CRSs and the warp/reproject tool within QGIS. I've also tried solving this problem with Python, but I wasn't sure how to do it.

Comment: Try to manipulate your X data to X-180 or Long-180 then plot your data again. It should do the trick.