# Change QGIS Map Wraparound point

Tags: qgis

Working with QGIS 3.3.2. I have a shape file of country borders which I import as a vector, and an .nc file of air temperature that I import as a raster. Both use the EPSG 4326 CRS. However, as seen in the picture, they have different centerpoints, with the American continents appearing on the left of center in the shapes file and on the right of center in the temperature raster file.

Is there a way to change the wrap-around point such that the maps align?[image]

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416091/converting-a-netcdf-from-0-to-360-to-180-to-180-via-xarray, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/467126/qgis-loads-netcdf-data-offset-from-map https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77484/longitude-range-netcdf-vs-ascii https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126747/what-coordinate-system-is-this-netcdf-raster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the coordinates of the raster file are from 0 to 360 and need to be reset to -180 to 180. I used the cdo utility to output a new raster file with the adjusted coordinates:
`cdo sellonlatbox,-180,180,-90,90 original_raster_file.nc adjusted_raster_file.nc`